# R Remove all rows from dataframe with specific ID based on conditional

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R that looks like this:

```
example <- matrix(c(1,1,2,3,3,50,90,85,80,100), ncol=2)
colnames(example) <- c('id', 'score')
example_df <- data.frame(example)


   id score
1:  1 50
2:  1 90
3:  2 10
4:  2 85
5:  3 80
6:  3 100
```

For each unique ID, I want to remove all rows for that ID if it has obtained a score in between 20 and 60. In that case, my resulting dataframe would look like

```
   id score
1:  2 10
2:  2 85
3:  3 80
5:  3 100
```

because id 1 had a score of 50 which within the range of 20 to 60, so we remove all rows with ID 1. How would I do this?
I've thought about using `group by` but it seems like dplyr verbs like `min` `max` and `mean` wouldn't help in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `data.table` would be to convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT`), grouped by 'id', check if there are not (`!`) `any` 'score' `between` 20 and 60, get the row index (`.I`), extract as a column (`$V1`) and use that in `i` to subset the rows

```
library(data.table)
setDT(example_df)[example_df[, .I[!any(between(score, 20, 60))], by = id]$V1]
```

---

Or a similar option in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
example_df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    filter(!any(between(score, 20, 60))) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#     id score
#  <int> <int>
#1     2    10
#2     2    85
#3     3    80
#4     3   100
```

#### data

```
example_df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), score = c(50L, 
90L, 10L, 85L, 80L, 100L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1:", 
"2:", "3:", "4:", "5:", "6:"))
```

Answer (score 2):

in Base R you could do:

```
 subset(example_df, ave(score>60|score<20, id, FUN = all))
   id score
3:  2    10
4:  2    85
5:  3    80
6:  3   100
```

or even:

```
subset(example_df, !ave(score<60&score>20, id, FUN = any))
   id score
3:  2    10
4:  2    85
5:  3    80
6:  3   100
```